# Post build testing with omake

Tags: post-build, omake

Is there any way to add a post build command to an omakefile?  I want it to automatically run unit tests everytime a build is successful, but am not sure of the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add commands to the .DEFAULT target. For example:

```
FILES[] =
    ...

CXXProgram(unittests, $(FILES))

.DEFAULT: unittests$(EXE)
    ./unittests$(EXE)
```

When invoked without any particular target, Omake will build all default targets, then run associated commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use .BUILD_SUCCESS and .BUILD_FAILURE targets for that purpose.
See details [here](http://omake.metaprl.org/manual/omake-build.html#chapter%3abuild).